# Not able to parse JSON file with Pandas

Tags: python, json, pandas, parsing

```
df=pd.read_json("https://api.covid19india.org/state_district_wise.json")
df

ab = df.transpose()
ab
```

I am trying to parse districtData from this api and I am not able to do it. The column has key value data in single quotes and it is giving error while parsing.

It will be very helpful if someone can help me with this issue.

Comment: I just got the data and used a JSON validation on it and it passed.. It may have just been a error from their API that was fixed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your correctly, you are looking for something along the below. And you don't need to go through pandas:

```
import requests
import json
from jsonpath_ng import jsonpath, parse

req = requests.get('https://api.covid19india.org/state_district_wise.json')
dat = json.loads(req.text)
j_ex = parse('[*]..districtData')
for match in j_ex.find(dat):
    print(match.value)
```

Output:

```
{'Unassigned': {'notes': '', 'active': 7955, 'confirmed': 7955, 'deceased': 0, 'recovered': 0, 'delta': {'confirmed': 0, 'deceased': 0, 'recovered': 0}}}
{'Nicobars': {'notes': '', 'active': 0, 'confirmed': 0, 'deceased': 0, 'recovered': 0, 'delta': {'confirmed': 0, 'deceased': 0, 'recovered': 0}}, 'North and Middle Andaman': {'notes': '', 'active': 0, 'confirmed': 1, 'deceased': 0, 'recovered': 1, 'delta': {'confirmed': 0, 'deceased': 0, 'recovered': 0}}, 'South Andaman': {'notes': '', 'active': 0, 'confirmed': 32, 'deceased': 0, 'recovered': 32, 'delta': {'confirmed': 0, 'deceased': 0, 'recovered': 0}}, 'Unknown': {'notes': '', 'active': 5, 'confirmed': 5, 'deceased': 0, 'recovered': 0, 'delta': {'confirmed': 0, 'deceased': 0, 'recovered': 0}}}
```

etc.

Comment: Hi Jack, Thanks for the response. I was actually able to get till this point. But, I want to modify above output mentioned by you in the form of a pandas dataframe. The JSON format contains the name of the districts in each of the Indian state. I want to extract all the district wise data.

Comment: @ChinmayJape I'm not sure I understand. Can you edit your question and add an example of what exactly your expected output is from a sample of the data?

Comment: I normalized the JSON data and created a data frame. The issue got resolved. But your approach to parse data was very helpful. Thanks again for the help.